# Checking whether javascript is enabled or not

Tags: javascript

Is there a JavaScript function to tell me if JavaScript is turned on or not? something like this one:

```
<script>
    if (true) {
        document.write("JavaScript is turned on!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How are you envisioning the ability to check whether JavaScript is enabled *using JavaScript*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683594/check-whether-javascript-is-enabled/6683647#6683647 explains how to use `<noscript>` with a meta redirect to take an action that will be apparent to the server when JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: [Bulletproof JavaScript Detection](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Bulletproof-JavaScript-Detection.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If it is enabled, the code runs. If it is not enabled the code does not run. There is nothing that is sent to the server that tells you if it is enabled.

Have you looked at the [noscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/noscript) element?

Comment: But i mean is there a way to check whether javascript is enabled or not?

Comment: No, there is no way. The code runs or it doesn't. What are you trying to find out exactly?

Comment: i was just willing to know.Thats it

Comment: The JavaScript runs if it is enabled. If it is not the code just sits there. The noscript tag can be used to give the user an option if JS is disabled or it can be used to redirect the user with the user of meta tags.

Comment: Actually iirc there is a header / userAgent something that's sent to server telling if JS is disabled...

Comment: no nvm , i got confused with something else ...

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the noscript tag

```
<noscript>
Enable javascript man! 
<noscript>
```

Or:

```
<script>
document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Comment: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Why use crap like w3schools, when the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/noscript.html) and [mozdev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/noscript) are readily available.

Comment: Because if you use google w3schools is the first result. Also the spec is incomprehensible to the average noob. Mozdev is good but is somewhat limited in scope.

Comment: Do you prefer frequently wrong & always scummy to incomprehensible or limited in scope?

Comment: If it works, yeah. Do you have common+recent(2010+) examples of things that have been wrong (genuine question)? I just see so much w3schools hate but I'm not sure it's warranted.

Comment: Fair enough.  I looked through w3fools to see if there are still obvious errors and I didn't have to go far, and their take on http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp is still valid.  It looks like w3fools has kept up-to-date.