# check noscript and log this status to db

Tags: javascript, php, noscript

On web page, I want to check whether the user has no script available.

Just after the check, I want to write something on php code (like put some log in db).

I have checked on some sites, such as:
[PHP & <noscript> combination to detect enabled JavaScript in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121743/php-noscript-combination-to-detect-enabled-javascript-in-browser)

and [Check whether Javascript is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683594/check-whether-javascript-is-enabled)
but the problem is, that the server side will have $_COOKIE or $_SESSION set as wanted (for the check) only after the page is reloaded again.

I want to check on php, that the client doesn't support javascript, just on first clicking the page (no need clicking it twice).

How can I do that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `noscript` section you could load a resource from your server. If the a visitor loads the resource, you know that he has JavaScript disabled.

Comment: OK, thank you. I see that the php run after the whole html had been loaded (not while loading), but since I know that fact, I can check later the consequences (such as writing to db) only after the loading of the page - that's OK with me. Thanks anyway